# Using TOP in select statements SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return only 10 rows, corresponding to the 10 vendors who've been paid the most but I can't seem to figure out how to use the TOP clause to grab the top 10 vendors who've been paid the most.

```
Select Top 10 SUM(PaymentTotal) AS PaymentSum, VendorName
From Invoices JOIN Vendors
On Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
Group By VendorName;
```

Comment: Can you clarify which database you are using.

Comment: `order by sum(PaymentTotal) desc`

Comment: The order by worked thank you GSerg

Comment: @GSerg Then I think you should write an answer, in order to let OP mark it as accepted, since your comment resolved the issue. :)

Comment: @AlbertoSolano At first I thought it was redundant because Hamlet Hakobyan has already [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21967160/11683) it, but now I realize his code won't actually compile because he's using a column alias instead of the column expression in the `order by`, so I'm posting it then :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Top 10
  sum(PaymentTotal) AS PaymentSum,
  VendorName
From
  Invoices
  INNER JOIN Vendors On Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
Group By
  VendorName
Order By
  sum(PaymentTotal) desc
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 10 SUM(PaymentTotal) AS PaymentSum, VendorName
From Invoices JOIN Vendors
On Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
Group By VendorName
order by PaymentSum dsec;
```